# Is there any native Mac OS X 10.15.3 keyboard layout that contains all ASCII characters plus č, ç, è, ǩ, ò, š, and ž?

Tags: macos, keyboard, text, input-source, text-input

I am creating a conlang that uses all ASCII characters plus č, ç, è, ǩ, ò, š, and ž. Is there any natively supported Mac OS X 10.15.3 keyboard that contains these special characters?

Comment: Apple does have a list of keyboard layouts available. Apart from checking those that are relevant by eye I don’t have another suggestion.

Comment: Try in Spotlight, Pages, TextEdit: type a character, eg. ```c```, keep pressed and a small popup appear with accented chars, and below them there is a digit, make a choice and press the corresponding digit and that letter will be inserted into your text. Only the ```k``` letter has no popup. Works with international keyboard, US English.

Comment: If there is not one you can use Karabinier to provide a mapping that does

Answer (score 2):

ABC Extended can make all those and more I think.

https://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/mac/codemacext/

but it's easy to make a custom layout with whatever you want using

https://software.sil.org/ukelele/

Comment: ABC Extended doesn't contain ç.

Comment: @Galactic. Do you not get that when you type Option c, then c?  ç